# AWS auth Cookie storage is not encoding the plus(+) character

Tags: angular, aws-amplify, ngx-cookie-service, awscognitotoken

I have the below code

```
const config = awsconfig;
config.cookieStorage = { domain: "mydomain", path: "/", expires: 365, sameSite: "lax", secure: true };
```

For example, if the email id arunk@gmail.com, is getting stored as expected.
ie : `CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.727vitcmg8qrnffc3lmrnb9.arunk%40gmail.com.accessToken`

But for the mail id arunk+1@gmail.com

```
CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.727vitcmg8qrnffc3lmrnb9.arunk+1%40gmail.com.accessToken
```

But the expected should be

```
CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.727vitcmg8qrnffc3lmrnb9.arunk%2B1%40gmail.com.accessToken
```

So the + character is not is getting encoded.
Since I am using **ngx-cookie-service** in my **angular** project, this cookie is not getting deleted.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot please? AWS Amplify uses `js-cookie` under the hood which should encode it.

Answer (score 0):

The **`+`** character is properly encoded in your cookie value; you can manually encode it before storing it in the cookie. You can use the JavaScript `encodeURIComponent()` function to achieve this:

```
const config = awsconfig;
const email = "arunk+1@gmail.com"; // Replace with your actual email address
const encodedEmail = encodeURIComponent(email);
config.cookieStorage = { domain: "mydomain", path: "/", expires: 365, sameSite: "lax", secure: true };

// Now, use the encoded email when setting the cookie value
const cookieValue = `CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.727vitcmg8qrnffc3lmrnb9.${encodedEmail}.accessToken`;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the problem is you don't have an option to set cookies manually.
This line code already set the cookie
config.cookieStorage = { domain: "mydomain", path: "/", expires: 365, sameSite: "lax", secure: true };